# Spring Starter Project not working when selecting gradle

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Using STS 3.7.1 Spring Starter Project, here are my selections then the error.

In the first screen I selected Gradle Project and War and left everything else as default.

[New Spring Starter Project screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycwc5.png)

In the second screen I selected Security, Actuator, AOP, Web, Atomikos(JTA), Jersy (JAX-RS), JPA, Rest Repositories, PostgreSQL, HATEOAS.

[New Spring Starter Project screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeKBF.png)

Then when I click finish it downloads a bunch of stuff then stops and gives this error:

'Import Getting Started Content' has encountered a problem.
NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet.addCollection(Lorg/gradle/api/DomainObjectCollection;)Lorg/gradle/api/internal/CompositeDomainObjectSet;
org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDomainObjectSet.addCollection(Lorg/gradle/api/DomainObjectCollection;)Lorg/gradle/api/internal/CompositeDomainObjectSet;

It creates the files on my disk but does not create the project in STS.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't mention if you have the Gradle plugin >http://docs.spring.io/sts/docs/2.9.0.old/reference/html/gradle/installation.html

Comment: I verified the latest version of the Gradle Extension is installed. That is Gradel IDE 3.7.1.201510041001-RELEASE

Comment: I recommend not to use war packaging with gradle because gradle's tooling API doesn't properly support WTP projects. This may not be the problem here though. It sounds more like a mismatch between the tooling api and gradle version. As the tooling api is supposed to work with different versions of gradle this is probably a bug in gradle tooling API or gradle.

Comment: I just tried what you described and the project imported fine for me. Have you by any chance changed any of the gradle tooling preferences (windows >> Preferences >> Gradle). For example have you enabled 'Custom tooling model' or 'Remap Jars to Gradle project?).

Comment: I can't see anything I changed, however I tried restoring to defaults and I am getting the same error. I'm not sure if this was a problem before updating, but I updated all available updates on 10/28/2015 just before I tried. I am also getting the same error when trying to import a Getting Started Guide with the gradle option selected. I am successfully using gradle for multiple custom projects though.